# Getting recommendation with user subscription

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-personalize

I am creating a campaign in AWS Personalize, where I am storing Items Interactions which seems to be giving good results.
Now, I am trying to include some restrictions as per user subscriptions, as some users may have access to an item or not.

I included the subscription under user metadata. But it does not seem to be working correctly, as two users are receiving recommendations of the same item, but they have different subscriptions.

Did anyone achieve this result? Or, anyone knows if this capability is in place?

**Notice:** I have followed the same steps as before included that, so after including user metadata, I create a new recipe, new solution, and solution version, as well the campaign to get those results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make use of filtering based on metadata feature, that was just added a week ago:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/07/amazon-personalize-enhances-recommendation-filters-with-filtering-on-item-metadata/

It requires to have Metadata specified in datasets and then you can make use of Filter creation wizard, to create correct filter:

```
INCLUDE ItemId where Interactions.SUBSCRIPTION_PLAN IN ("silver_user", "gold_user")
```

So in this case, all of the items that has metadata `SUBSCRIPTION_PLAN` value `silver_user` or `gold_user` will be filtered in during generation of recommendations.

I believe that it's also very simple to make use of Personalize built-in wizard for creating filter expressions, which can be found in AWS Personalize console in Filters tab.

And make sure that your data is correctly categorized:

> For metadata datasets, all strings, except for USER_ID and ITEM_ID, must be marked as categorical in the schema, as shown in the following examples.

Comment: is it a free service, I mean filters? or will add additional cost? as I am facing the same issue. thanks. hope to answer as it is an old question.

Comment: Yes, it's a free feature, you will pay for TPS anyways :)

Comment: Thanks, can you check my question as it is a headache in my head for a week. I think you have a unique answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66292795/how-to-solve-multi-vendor-problem-in-aws-personalize